# Which city can be seen on this Windows 10 lock screen photo featuring a stadium next to a river?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

This picture is currently my lock screen on my Windows 10 laptop, but nowhere can I find any captions which tell me which city this actually is. I also tried reverse Googling. No results.

I asked my geography teacher; he doesn't know either. The city looks like it is in a dry area (river banks); also, the building next to that "castle" looks like a mosque to me. So maybe it's some Oriental city, but it also looks very modern.

[image]

Comment: Might that be the Danube?

Comment: @gerrit I already wondered if it is Vienna, but my teacher is from Vienna and he doesn't recognize the city, so I don't think so.

Comment: A reverse Google image search actually returns results on both istockphoto and gettyimages for that picture.

Comment: @jcaron Maybe with your google, I just received images of other stadions or other cities, none of them were the same as in the photo.

Comment: I just used the link of the picture above. Note that the "good" results are not in the "Visually similar images" section, but in the "Pages that include matching images" section.

Comment: @jcaron Google searches are "personalized", so there's no guarantee that what you get on the first page of hits will show up at the top of someone else's search (or even within the first few pages of results). I have seen three different people run an image search for "cheese balls" at the same time; one got images of the packaged snack food, another got ball-shaped cheese dip, and the third got batter-fried chunks of cheese. So all three were "proven correct" about their interpretation of the term (and never would have learned that there was any other possibility if it were up to Google).

Comment: "So maybe its some oriental city, but it also looks very modern." How is that an oxymoron?

Comment: >I also tried reverse googling. No results. Really? I queried with the image, and got: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pN75.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pN75.jpg) and the rest of the page is crawling with *Kazan, Russian* results. In the future, you might want to query like this. =)

Comment: In Windows 10, you have an option (the Earth logo) on the lock screen page that opens a Bing page for the location of the picture.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an FAQ for this somewhere. "How do I find the Windows 10 photo info?"

Comment: This functionality (name of the place/picture) is actually broken on certain versions/installations of Win 10 (usually enterprise ones, i think), so it might lack the globe and the name.

Answer (score 43):

It's [Kazan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazan), Russia, which is where the FIFA World Cup is being played right now (in 2018).

The stadium in the foreground is the Tsentralnyi Stadion, with the Kazan Kremlin just beyond. The river is the Kazanka River.

The image is a stock image from Getty Images which you can find [here](https://www.gettyimages.co.nz/detail/photo/kazan-from-the-air-royalty-free-image/903711510)

Comment: The old central stadium to be exact.

Comment: I guess how did you find this?

Comment: The stadium, kremlin, and mosque are all visible in [this satellite view](https://www.google.com/maps/@55.7959287,49.1010841,2853m/data=!3m1!1e3) on Google Maps.

Comment: @JonH right-clicking the image and choose "Search Google for image" on Chrome works very well on this case...